# Using more than one object to iterate though in foreach loops

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a multidimensional list:

```
    List<string>[] list = new List<string>[2];
    list[0] = new List<string>();
    list[1] = new List<string>();
```

And I iterate though the list as follows - but this only iterates through one list:

```
foreach (String str in dbConnectObject.Select()[0])
{
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Although I want to be able to do something like:

```
foreach (String str in dbConnectObject.Select()[0] & String str2 in dbConnectObject.Select()[1])
{
   Console.WriteLine(str + str2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the lists are of the same size, you can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
foreach (var p in dbConnectObject.Select()[0].Zip(dbConnectObject.Select()[1], (a,b) => new {First = a, Second = b})) {
    Console.Writeline("{0} {1}", p.First, p.Second);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sequentially iterate through the two lists, you can use [`IEnumerable<T>.Union(IEnumerable<T>)` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) :

```
IEnumerable<string> union = list[0].Union(list[1]);

foreach(string str int union)
{
     DoSomething(str);
}
```

If you want a matrix of combination, you can join the lists :

```
var joined = from str1 in list[0]
             from str2 in list[1]
             select new { str1, str2};


foreach(var combination in joined)
{
    //DoSomethingWith(combination.str1, combination.str2);
    Console.WriteLine(str + str2);
}
```

Comment: `Union` will exclude duplicates from the return set. I don't think that this is desired. I would prefer `Concat` although `Zip` might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. It also works if the sizes differ.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
{
    var str0 = list[0][i];
    Console.WriteLine(str0);
    if (list[1].Count > i)
    {
        var str1 = list[1][i];
        Console.WriteLine(str1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Enumerable` extension methods on pure `Lists`? (`Count()` instead of Count, `ElementAt` instead of the indexer)

Answer (score -1):

Use LINQ instead:

`foreach (var s in list.SelectMany(l => l))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}`

Comment: Ths does not join both lists with each other.